# Referring to an event that occurred before another event in the past

Tags: past-tense

I'm writing about an event(A) in the past and relating this to another event (B) which occurred before the first event. Which is a better way to frame this:

In the backdrop of the September 11 attacks which happened two months ago, the capture of Kabul ...

Is it better to use 'prior' or 'earlier' instead of 'ago'?

Answer (score 0):

Using "ago" to refer to the older event would be incorrect. 
You are right in suggesting "prior"

> In the backdrop of the September 11 attacks, which happened two months prior to the capture of Kabul, thousands were killed ...

Alternatively,

> In the backdrop of the September 11 attacks which happened two months before the capture of Kabul, thousands were killed ...